# Accessing a bean with a dot(.) in its ID

Tags: java, spring, spring-webflow, spring-el

In a flow definition, I am trying to access a bean that has a dot in its ID

(example: `<evaluate expression="bus.MyServiceFacade.someAction()" />`

However, it does not work. SWF tries to find a bean "bus" instead.

Initially, I got over it by using a helper bean to load the required bean, but the solution is inelegant and uncomfortable. The use of alias'es is also out of the question since the beans are part of a large system and I cannot tamper with them.

In a nutshell, none of the solution allowed me to refernce the bean directly by using its original name. Is that even possible in the current SWF release?

Answer (score 10):

I was able to do this by using both the bean accessor (`@`) symbol and single-quotes around the name of the bean.

Using your example: `#{@'bus.MyServiceFacade'.someAction()}`

Answer (score 1):

This is a restriction of the EL parser (generally either OGNL or jboss-el for Spring Web Flow). EL uses dot notation for parsing the navigation chain,causing the initial behavior you describe (attempting to find the "bus" bean).

Answer (score 0):

Try:

['bus.MyServiceFacade'].someAction()

or

'bus.MyServiceFacade'.someAction()

This may work, or it may not...but similar things are used in the Expression Language for JSPs.

Answer (score -1):

In my experience, anything with a getter method can be accessed via dot notation.  In your example, whatever object is being represented by the `bus` bean needs to have a `getServiceFacade` method and that the object returned by `getServiceFacade` would need to have a `getSomeAction` method.