# Access to bean by SpEL in @PreAuthorize with FullyQualifiedAnnotationBeanNameGenerator

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, spring-expression-language, spring-expression

I have controller with method that have logic for checking permission:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/example")
public class ExampleController {

    @GetMapping
    @PreAuthorize("@exampleController.hasPermission()")
    public String example() {
        return "hello";
    }

    public boolean hasPermission() {
        return true; // complex logic
    }
}
```

As you can see I use SpEL to call that method (by bean name: `exampleController`).

But if I change bean name generator to `FullyQualifiedAnnotationBeanNameGenerator`:

```
@SpringBootApplication(nameGenerator = FullyQualifiedAnnotationBeanNameGenerator.class)
```

now bean name is `com.example.demo.ExampleController` (checked in debuger).

Following this I try to change bean name in `@PreAuthorized`:

```
@PreAuthorize("@com.example.demo.ExampleController.hasPermission()")
```

but it doesn't work:

```
Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception 
  [Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException:
  Failed to evaluate expression '@com.example.demo.ExampleController.hasPermission()'] with root cause
org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'com' available
```

How to refer to bean with dots in name in SpEL?
Or how to call method from controller in a different way (without using bean name)?

I know I can implement custom `AnnotationBeanNameGenerator` without special characters. But I'm expecting that Spring's bean name generator is compatible with SpEL (Spring Expression Language).

#### Update

Answers from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62713/accessing-a-bean-with-a-dot-in-its-id/14408583#14408583) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17539056/how-do-i-reference-a-bean-in-spring-el-named-with-a-prefix/17542313#17542313) don't work either (I guess it worked in XML config, but not in annotations):

```
@PreAuthorize("#{@'com.example.demo.ExampleController'.hasPermission()}")
```

```
Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: 
  Failed to parse expression '#{@'com.example.demo.ExampleController'.hasPermission()}'
```

#### Update 2

Full stack trace (for @dur):

```
ERROR [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'com.example.demo.ExampleController' defined in file [(...)/demo/target/classes/com/example/demo/ExampleController.class]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to parse expression '#{@'com.example.demo.ExampleController'.hasPermission()}'
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:628) ~[spring-beans-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:542) ~[spring-beans-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335) ~[spring-beans-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333) ~[spring-beans-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208) ~[spring-beans-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:955) ~[spring-beans-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:918) ~[spring-context-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:583) ~[spring-context-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:147) ~[spring-boot-2.7.5.jar:2.7.5]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:734) ~[spring-boot-2.7.5.jar:2.7.5]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:408) ~[spring-boot-2.7.5.jar:2.7.5]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:308) ~[spring-boot-2.7.5.jar:2.7.5]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1306) ~[spring-boot-2.7.5.jar:2.7.5]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1295) ~[spring-boot-2.7.5.jar:2.7.5]
    at com.example.demo.DemoApplication.main(DemoApplication.java:11) ~[classes/:na]
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to parse expression '#{@'com.example.demo.ExampleController'.hasPermission()}'
    at org.springframework.security.access.expression.method.ExpressionBasedAnnotationAttributeFactory.createPreInvocationAttribute(ExpressionBasedAnnotationAttributeFactory.java:59) ~[spring-security-core-5.7.4.jar:5.7.4]
    at org.springframework.security.access.prepost.PrePostAnnotationSecurityMetadataSource.getAttributes(PrePostAnnotationSecurityMetadataSource.java:80) ~[spring-security-core-5.7.4.jar:5.7.4]
    at org.springframework.security.access.method.DelegatingMethodSecurityMetadataSource.getAttributes(DelegatingMethodSecurityMetadataSource.java:66) ~[spring-security-core-5.7.4.jar:5.7.4]
    at org.springframework.security.access.intercept.aopalliance.MethodSecurityMetadataSourceAdvisor$MethodSecurityMetadataSourcePointcut.matches(MethodSecurityMetadataSourceAdvisor.java:127) ~[spring-security-core-5.7.4.jar:5.7.4]
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.canApply(AopUtils.java:252) ~[spring-aop-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.canApply(AopUtils.java:289) ~[spring-aop-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.findAdvisorsThatCanApply(AopUtils.java:321) ~[spring-aop-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.findAdvisorsThatCanApply(AbstractAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.java:128) ~[spring-aop-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.findEligibleAdvisors(AbstractAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.java:97) ~[spring-aop-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.getAdvicesAndAdvisorsForBean(AbstractAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.java:78) ~[spring-aop-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAutoProxyCreator.wrapIfNecessary(AbstractAutoProxyCreator.java:341) ~[spring-aop-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAutoProxyCreator.postProcessAfterInitialization(AbstractAutoProxyCreator.java:293) ~[spring-aop-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyBeanPostProcessorsAfterInitialization(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:455) ~[spring-beans-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1808) ~[spring-beans-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:620) ~[spring-beans-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    ... 15 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelParseException: Expression [#{@'com.example.demo.ExampleController'.hasPermission()}] @1: EL1043E: Unexpected token. Expected 'identifier' but was 'lcurly({)'
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.standard.InternalSpelExpressionParser.internalException(InternalSpelExpressionParser.java:1041) ~[spring-expression-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.standard.InternalSpelExpressionParser.eatToken(InternalSpelExpressionParser.java:923) ~[spring-expression-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.standard.InternalSpelExpressionParser.maybeEatFunctionOrVar(InternalSpelExpressionParser.java:421) ~[spring-expression-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.standard.InternalSpelExpressionParser.eatStartNode(InternalSpelExpressionParser.java:510) ~[spring-expression-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.standard.InternalSpelExpressionParser.eatPrimaryExpression(InternalSpelExpressionParser.java:350) ~[spring-expression-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.standard.InternalSpelExpressionParser.eatUnaryExpression(InternalSpelExpressionParser.java:344) ~[spring-expression-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.standard.InternalSpelExpressionParser.eatPowerIncDecExpression(InternalSpelExpressionParser.java:303) ~[spring-expression-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.standard.InternalSpelExpressionParser.eatProductExpression(InternalSpelExpressionParser.java:281) ~[spring-expression-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.standard.InternalSpelExpressionParser.eatSumExpression(InternalSpelExpressionParser.java:263) ~[spring-expression-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.standard.InternalSpelExpressionParser.eatRelationalExpression(InternalSpelExpressionParser.java:218) ~[spring-expression-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.standard.InternalSpelExpressionParser.eatLogicalAndExpression(InternalSpelExpressionParser.java:205) ~[spring-expression-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.standard.InternalSpelExpressionParser.eatLogicalOrExpression(InternalSpelExpressionParser.java:192) ~[spring-expression-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.standard.InternalSpelExpressionParser.eatExpression(InternalSpelExpressionParser.java:153) ~[spring-expression-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.standard.InternalSpelExpressionParser.doParseExpression(InternalSpelExpressionParser.java:131) ~[spring-expression-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.standard.SpelExpressionParser.doParseExpression(SpelExpressionParser.java:61) ~[spring-expression-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.standard.SpelExpressionParser.doParseExpression(SpelExpressionParser.java:33) ~[spring-expression-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.expression.common.TemplateAwareExpressionParser.parseExpression(TemplateAwareExpressionParser.java:52) ~[spring-expression-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.expression.common.TemplateAwareExpressionParser.parseExpression(TemplateAwareExpressionParser.java:43) ~[spring-expression-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.security.access.expression.method.ExpressionBasedAnnotationAttributeFactory.createPreInvocationAttribute(ExpressionBasedAnnotationAttributeFactory.java:53) ~[spring-security-core-5.7.4.jar:5.7.4]
    ... 29 common frames omitted
```

Even Intellij says something is wrong:
[image]

#### Update 3 (resolved)

It works ([thanks for](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77410680/access-to-bean-by-spel-in-preauthorize-with-fullyqualifiedannotationbeannamegen?noredirect=1#comment136523441_77410680) @dur):

```
@PreAuthorize("@'com.example.demo.ExampleController'.hasPermission()")
```

But Intellij mislead me it won't work:
[image]

Comment: I looked into the class [`Tokenizer.`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/main/spring-expression/src/main/java/org/springframework/expression/spel/standard/Tokenizer.java) and it can't read identifiers with `.`. So you need to use an alias for your bean.

Comment: I looked into [`InternalSpelExpressionParser`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/main/spring-expression/src/main/java/org/springframework/expression/spel/standard/InternalSpelExpressionParser.java) and it should work with quotes.

Comment: Could you add the full stack trace of your quoted version?

Comment: Could you check, if it works without `#{` and `}`? AFAIR this is only used in Thymeleaf templates.

Comment: It works! IntelliJ says that's wrong, but it works. ("Update 3" in question)

Comment: I've just found reported bug in IntelliJ: [1](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-315414/Valid-SPEL-expression-referering-to-quoted-bean-with-dot-in-name-marked-as-error), [2](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-269571/SpEL-bean-reference-is-error-highlighted-if-the-bean-name-appears-in-single-quotes-after-the-bean-accessor-symbol) and related [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59771574/how-to-reference-a-bean-by-type-in-a-spel/59802069#59802069).